# Type error using generics under java 8, but not java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, java-8

I have a piece of code which compiles fine under java 7, but not under java 8. Here is a self-contained reproducing example (I've taken real code that exhibits this problem and stubbed out all the implementations):

```
import java.util.Iterator;

class ASTNode<T extends ASTNode> implements Iterable<T> {
  @Override public Iterator<T> iterator() { return null; }
}

class List<T extends ASTNode> extends ASTNode<T> {}

interface Function<F, T> {}

class Iterables {
  public static <F,T> Iterable<T> transform(
      Iterable<F> fromIterable, Function<? super F, ? extends T> function) { return null; }
}

class AstFunctions {
  public static <T extends ASTNode<?>> Function<T, String> prettyPrint() { return null; }
}

public class Main {
  public static void test() {
    List<? extends ASTNode<?>> list = null;
    Iterables.transform(list, AstFunctions.prettyPrint());
  }
}
```

Witness:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_05

$ javac -source 1.7 Main.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning

$ javac -source 1.8 Main.java
Main.java:23: error: method transform in class Iterables cannot be applied to given types;
    Iterables.transform(list, AstFunctions.prettyPrint());
             ^
  required: Iterable<F>,Function<? super F,? extends T#1>
  found: List<CAP#1>,Function<ASTNode<?>,String>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) F,T#1,T#2
    (argument mismatch; Function<CAP#1,String> cannot be converted to Function<? super CAP#1,? extends String>)
  where F,T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    F extends Object declared in method <F,T#1>transform(Iterable<F>,Function<? super F,? extends T#1>)
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <F,T#1>transform(Iterable<F>,Function<? super F,? extends T#1>)
    T#2 extends ASTNode<?> declared in method <T#2>prettyPrint()
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends ASTNode<?> from capture of ? extends ASTNode<?>
1 error
```

(Perhaps notable is that Eclipse, configured for 1.8 compatibility, has no issues with this code).

Is this a compiler bug? If not, then assuming I'm allowed to change `AstFunctions` and `Main` (but not `ASTNode`, `List`, `Function`, or `Iterables`), how can I make this code compile? I'd also like to understand, if possible, what change to Java 8's type system makes this code not compile.

Comment: What happens if you try the development version of Eclipse? It probably won't solve the compiler error, but you might be able to get more info out of Eclipse instead of breaking it

Comment: @user3580294 I just tried with 4.4RC1 and got exactly the same internal compiler error :\

Comment: Oh really? I'd highly recommend submitting a bug report then, since I think they'd want to fix this before 4.4 goes live. Sorry to hear that didn't work though...

Comment: I think this will take one of SO's Java 8 experts (@BrianGoetz, maybe?) to solve, to be honest. I can't imagine there being many people who know enough about how Java's type inference system works to answer this very quickly...

Comment: @user3580294 I filed a bug here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435463

Comment: Just a suggestion, they usually appreciate you providing a test case that shows your bug. What I normally do with my projects is copy everything to a new project and start deleting everything I know isn't necessary until I reach a point where any change I make will cause the error to vanish. Also might want to consider raising the priority on the bug.

Comment: Also, if you manage to do that, do you mind posting that small set of code here? I would love to try poking around this myself.

Comment: @user3580294 I'm having trouble reproducing the Eclipse problem, but I've replaced the question with a self-contained sample reproducing the javac problem.

Comment: Hmmm, did the `StackOverflowError` happen only one time? Or does it only happen with your full code? In any case, if you're comfortable in doing so you could attach your entire project, but I think they'd understand if you don't want to. Might want to leave a comment saying so though.

Comment: Interestingly, your code pasted into Eclipse for me has no errors when I don't import Google Guava...

Comment: This is interesting... Eclipse for me compiles this just fine, while `javac -source 1.8` (but not `1.7`, like you said) emits an error. Wonder what's going on... I'm on Eclipse 4.4 M7, Build ID 20140508-1440. Does the code you posted give an error in Eclipse? I wonder if you just discovered a bug in `javac` or the Eclipse compiler... Do you have any other IDEs to try?

Comment: @user3580294 The code in the question here compiles fine with Eclipse, but the code in my project gives the StackOverflowError. Maybe it's a coincidence that it's the same file... I've added instructions to try and reproduce on the bug page (the code is open source).

Comment: Yep, I CC'd your bug report, so I saw the comment. I suppose now the mystery is why `javac` emits an error while we get nary a peep out of Eclipse for the reduced example, yet the larger one causes Eclipse to promptly break. I don't think there's anything we can do now but wait and hope that this gets more attention soon...

Comment: @IsmailBadawi before referring to a bug in the compiler you should first check that there is a bug in the last version of the compiler which you can obtain here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/langtools/. Raising and issue that is not an issue any more is just a red herring.

Comment: Related: OpenJDK bug filed referencing this question: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8043818

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: see other answer - this was a bug in javac which has been fixed.

---

<strike>It feels like this should not compile and that Java 8 is exhibiting the correct behaviour:</strike>

- `Iterables.transform` expects an `Iterable<F> fromIterable` and `Function<? super F...`, so the first generic type of `Function` needs to be a super class of the generic type of the `Iterable`
- in your main, the type of the Iterable is `F1 == ? extends ASTNode<?>` and the first type of the Function returned by `prettyPrint` is `F2 == T extends ASTNode<?>`

I don't think there is a way to prove that F2 is a supertype of F1. For example let's say you have:

```
class A1 extends ASTNode<A1> {}
class A2 extends ASTNode<A2> {}
```

and in your main:

```
List<? extends ASTNode<?>> list = new List<A1>(); //F1 = A1
```

You could imagine that `prettyPrint` returns a `Function<A2, String>` (i.e. `F2 = A2`) and A2 is not a super class of A1.

So I believe the compile error makes sense. But I won't try to prove it based on the specifications because that would eat most of my day!

Comment: Anyway, I think it boils down to *improvements* in Java 8 type inference, which properly detect that the code is not right.

Comment: Okay. Well I just replaced the call to `Iterables.transform` with a plain loop instead of dealing with these issues. Not worth the hassle!

Comment: Interestingly, at least one of the Eclipse maintainers [thinks otherwise](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435485)... No response from Oracle yet, and don't think there will be one anytime soon.

Comment: This answer is wrong as demonstrated by the fact that recent versions of javac8 and javac9 agree with ecj in accepting the program, see the answer by @Vicente Romero.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an issue in current version of the compiler at [last javac 9](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/langtools/). Any apparent bug should be checked against this version before any other consideration.

For last javac8 code the repository to check is [last javac 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/langtools). This issue has already been fixed in that repository. The issue has been fixed with the patch for [JDK-8033718](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8033718)

Comment: Why should a Java8 bug need to be checked against Java9 (beta)? Java8 is out for a few month and will be supported for years to come.

Comment: @Durandal, sorry for the super late answer, my point is that if the bug is fixed in 9 then we are not talking about a bug but about a changeset that should be backported to the java8. The process here should be to check against last javac and if it's fixed there then the next step is to find the changeset that made the difference.

Comment: compiler-dev@openjdk.java.net should be the place to ask about this issue